# Delete pdf pages in java with iTextpdf

Tags: java, itext

I have an existing function to show pdf files that I can't change.

The input of function is an `InputStream` variable.
In the past they used to pass a pdf file to it and it shows it.

But right now they asked me to show only first 30 pages of the pdf. So I am using `iTextpdf` and I do something like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader (inputStream);
reader.selectPages("1-30");
```

Now I should send the result as `InputStream` variable to show method.

How I should do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the result using a `PdfStamper` like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader (inputStream);
reader.selectPages("1-30");
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);
stamper.close();
byte[] changedPdf = os.toByteArray();
```

If you want the result again to be in the `InputStream inputStream` variable, simply add a line

```
inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(changedPdf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the reader of existing pdf file by

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("source pdf file path");
```

Now update the reader by

```
 reader.selectPages("1-5,15-20");
```

then get the pdf stamper object to write the changes into a file by

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
                new FileOutputStream("destination pdf file path"));
```

close the PdfStamper by

```
pdfStamper.close();
```

It will close the PdfReader too.